# Number Conversion, Getting Undefined

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I'm working on a program that, before it can do anything else, must be able to convert numbers into other numbers. The program only works with numbers 0 through 11 (representing music notes), so anything greater or less than that must be converted to a number between 0 and 11. But when I run my function, it returns undefined for a lot of numbers.

```
const TET = 12;
const Notes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

function NoteConverter(note) {
  const doubled = TET * 2;
  const tripled = TET * 3;

  for (index in Notes) {
    if (note == index) {
      return index;
    } else if (note == index + TET || note == index - TET) {
      return index;
    } else if (note == index + doubled || note == index - doubled) {
      return index;
    } else if (note == index + tripled || note == index - tripled) {
      return index;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the function using 15 as the number to be converted, I get undefined instead of 3, which it should convert to.

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong but can't. Any help?

Comment: Your `Notes` array is only 12 big. Your `for` will not get to 15, so you return `undefined` implicitly at the end of your function.

Comment: Never use `for...in` with arrays. Use `for...of` or use the  `.forEach(...)` iterator function. But also note that arrays have `.find(...)` and `findIndex(...)`, there is no need to write your own for loop here, just find the index and then do what you need to do?

Comment: Or in this case, since it's just a sequence of 0-11, just a plain old for loop will do: `for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++)`.

Comment: You could use the [modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to do this in one line - `return note % TET;`

Answer (score 0):

It will concatenate string for `index + TET` so for example if index is 0 `index + TET` will be `012` it happens because `typeof index` is `string` also it is string because the `in` keyword also works for objects so it would return key name for object which isn't always a number.

edit: so you either have to go with of notes as suggested in the other answer or make sure that it gets converted to number first ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace **in** with **of**

```js
const TET = 12;
const Notes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

function NoteConverter(note) {
  const doubled = TET * 2;
  const tripled = TET * 3;

  for (index of Notes) {
    if (note == index) {
      return index;
    } else if (note == index + TET || note == index - TET) {
      return index;
    } else if (note == index + doubled || note == index - doubled) {
      return index;
    } else if (note == index + tripled || note == index - tripled) {
      return index;
    }
  }
}

console.log(NoteConverter(15))
```